# how to convert webp image to jpeg or png by using intervention image laravel

Tags: image, laravel-5, gd, intervention, webp

I am developing an app in Laravel Framework (PHP). I want to upload image which have webp format and then convert it to jpeg or png image format. After converting the image i also want to upload it to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly we can use [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) library. We must have php 7 and gd library installed. I am writing the commands to install gd library and webp library below (for ubuntu) :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install webp
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd (check php version and then install accordingly)
```

now check file extension and if extension is webp, select your output file extension

```
$extension = $this->file->extension();

if($this->file->getMimeType() == 'image/webp'){
    $extension = 'png';
}
// Generate a random filename
$fileName = time() . '_' . strtolower(uniqid()) . '.' . $extension;
```

Now encode the image to desired format

```
if($this->file->getMimeType() == 'image/webp'){
    $image = $image->encode($extension);
}
$image = $image->stream();
```

Now upload the image to s3 bucket

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($folderName . '/' . $fileName, $imageNormal->__toString());
```